# Math.sin returns unexpected results

Tags: java

`Math.sin(Math.PI)` returns `1.2246467991473532E-16`

`Math.sin(-Math.PI)` returns `-1.2246467991473532E-16`

But mustn't it return zeros?

Though sin from `3.14` and `3.15` are correct.

Comment: Math.PI is not exactly  - so sin(Math.PI) is not exactly 0.

Comment: [Pi is trascendent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi).

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Math.PI` is not "exactly" π, it's just a roughly-16-digit approximation of π (3.141592653589793). No floating point format can store π exactly. That's why you don't get the exact zero.

Comment: the other problems are that Math.sin is not exactly sin, calculation is not precise in computer, and double representation is not precise representation of any real number, it rounded by ULP.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot exactly represent PI so you can't expect an exact result. I suggest you round off the result if you believe this is an error.

Print it as `(int)Math.sin(Math.PI)` , you will get 0

Note that `Math.sin` to an int will always give 0 or -1

Comment: `(int) Math.sin(1)` is also 0.

Comment: Moreover: `(int)Math.sin(x)` is always 0, because you can't represent `π/2` ^^

Comment: @moonwave99: Expanding sin(π/2 + ε) ~ 1 - ε^2/2 + ..., so even if you can't express π/2 exactly, the error from the result is much less than 1ulp from 1.0, so you still get 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

The nature of float point functions in computers is that they are not precise (see the link from Drop).

If you want to round values up to 2(or any) digit after point  for function you can do

```
    (Math.rint(1e2*Math.sin(Math.PI)))/1e2
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, the root cause is that `Math.PI` is not (and cannot be) exactly π. That already explains why the answer shouldn't be zero, but we can be a bit more specific about why the answer is 1.2246467991473532E-16 specifically.

The sine function near π can be approximated as `sin(π + ε) ≈ -ε` for small values of ε.

Rounding π to the nearest `double` results in a `double` with the value of (exactly) 3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875, which is what `Math.PI` is. That value is not (and couldn't be) exactly π, but it can be written as `π + ε` for some small ε  (that number is pretty close to π after all). Since `sin(π + ε) ≈ -ε`, `sin(Math.PI)` should actually give us `-ε`, rounded to the nearest `double`.

`π - Math.PI` is 1.22464679914735317722606593227500... × 10<sup>-16</sup> [according to Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=pi+-+3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875), 1.2246467991473532E-16 is a pretty good approximation of that.